# Experience in intergrating Atlassian Jira with HP's Service Manager/Quality Center?

Tags: hp, service, jira

I'm wondering whether anyone has had to look for solutions for integrating HP's Service Manager(which is a part of the HP Service Management Center).  Our NOC uses this for incident management and is looking into integrating it somehow with Jira/Confluence, for those employees/departments that don't use it. I come from the Jira side, and haven't looked at the HP suite in detail, but research shows there aren't any plugins available for Jira, except for[something called JaM](http://www.go2group.com/display/PORTAL/Go2Group+JaM+plugin) (which is really for Quality Center).

The only criteria is really that Service Manager can at least send incident reports to Jira, either via mail plugins or via webservices.

Can this be done? Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 2):

Within HP Service Manager you can build SOAP calls in the ScriptLibrary.  Essentially you would write up the custom function in JavaScript to publish Incidents, Changes, or Requests to Jira's Web Service.

You can get to ScriptLibrary from the Navigator Panel on the left.  I believe it is under the "Tailoring" directory.

One example of a web service call that HP provides out of the box is the Amazon Web Service Script.

Then in the JavaScript tab on the format control you would execute the script with the following:

system.library.SCRIPTNAME.FUNCTION(PARAMETERS)

(replace SCRIPTNAME, FUNCTION, and PARAMETERS with your values)

Format Controls: problem (Incident Management), incidents (Service Desk Interaction), ocmq (Request Quotes), cm3r (Change Management)

You can get to format control by typing "fc" in the command line at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If the HP app generates formatted email subjects, its possible the Nagios handler for the mail handler: [JEMH](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JEMH/JIRA+Extendable+Mail+Handler) can be setup to process those mails.  If you have 'related' mails, eg up/down, JEMH can auto-close your tickets for you.  Of course, if it doesnt quite fit, it can always be extended.